# Can I log into mongoDB from python 'line by line'?

Tags: python, mongodb

```
with open ('test.log', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

def log(msg):
    entry={}
    entry['timestamp']=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    entry['msg']=msg
    log_collection.insert(entry)

log(data)
```

Currently, the code above stores my log file (test.log in this case) into mongodb successfully.

However, the whole log file with many lines is stored into mongodb as 1 document.

Since my log file is separated by lines, is there any way to store the log file into mongodb line by line as many documents?

I have tried parsing it into lines but it is in array format so mongodb couldn't read it successfully.

Thanks!

*LOG Sample:*

```
{"asctime": "2019-11-19 04:12:06,414", "levelname": "DEBUG", "name": "passlib.registry", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": "registered 'pbkdf2_sha256' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256'>"}
{"asctime": "2019-11-19 04:12:06,459", "levelname": "INFO", "name": "werkzeug", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": " * Running on 0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)"}
```

Comment: Iterate over the array of lines, generate a new `entry` for each line, and `insert()` each `entry`. Alternatively, there should be some equivalent of an `insertMany()`, in which case you could perform a `map()` on the array to generate an array of `entry`s and pass the result into the `insertMany()` call.

Comment: in my case , I will use logstsh plugin  : https://medium.com/@shukla.devbrat1993/logstash-plug-in-and-logstash-configuration-to-sync-mongodb-data-into-elastic-search-400d88e6a180

Comment: Can you post a small sample of log data to see how these lines look like (it will be easy to make suggestions).

Comment: @prasad_  {"asctime": "2019-11-19 04:12:06,414", "levelname": "DEBUG", "name": "passlib.registry", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": "registered 'pbkdf2_sha256' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256'>"} {"asctime": "2019-11-19 04:12:06,459", "levelname": "INFO", "name": "werkzeug", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": " * Running on 0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)"} sorry for messy arrangement but it is many lines of this kind of json logs! and each line is separated by \n

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Would this work for flask backend?

Comment: No problem. You can edit your post anytime, for now I added it for you :)

Comment: Since each line is JSON format, are you planning importing into MongoDB using `mongoimport`?

Comment: @ktw Yes ....you can use in backend

Comment: I have a question @ktw ....do you want to analyse logs?... beacuse You can use better ELK (elasticsearch, logstash,Kibana) for that

Answer (score 0):

Your `read()` call reads the whole file into a single doc. Try this instead:

```
import json
import pymongo
import pprint

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = pymongo.MongoClient()
    db = client["logdb"]
    collection = db["logs"]
    with open("test.log", "r") as file:
        for line in file:              # python knows to iterate line by line
            line = line.rstrip()       # strip off the newline
            print(line)                # take a look
            doc = json.loads(line)     # convert the string to a doc
            pprint.pprint(doc)         # print doc
            collection.insert_one(doc) #insert, use insert_many() for better performance
```